# Create view and building Reports From an SQL View in Acumatica, duplicate data rows Version 5.30.1672

Tags: customization, acumatica

This is my view that I created in sql server:

```
  CREATE VIEW [dbo].[view_CaseAttribute] AS 
  SELECT a.CompanyID,a.CaseID,a.CaseCD,
  CaseAttribute=STUFF  
  (  
    (  
       SELECT ','+ CAST(b.Value AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
       FROM dbo.CSAnswers b   
       WHERE a.CaseID=b.EntityID and a.CompanyID='3' and b.CompanyID='3' and
       (b.AttributeID='POSPRODUCT' or b.AttributeID='POSMODULE' or b.AttributeID='POSFUNCTIO' or b.AttributeID='NATURE')
       FOR XMl PATH('')  
     ),1,1,''  
 )  
 FROM dbo.CRCase a  
 LEFT JOIN dbo.CSAnswers c ON a.CaseID=c.EntityID
 WHERE a.CompanyID='3' 
 GROUP BY a.CompanyID,a.CaseID,a.CaseCD 
 GO
```

(Picture-1) After then I create Customization Project

[image]

In Report Designer view_CaseAttribute join CRCase 
The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you DAC code.

you should have correct Key's defined for the fields.

Sample

```
[PXDBString(15, IsKey = true)]
```

Comment: But in Generic Inquiry it's okay, and after I add [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true)] it errors.

Comment: i just gave you a sample. you should use the 'iskey = true' in your correct key fields.